# How to change the background color in DropDownButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, dropdown

I watched the [official](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) DropDownButton example and the background is always gray when pressed for a long time, how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `DropdownButton` is on focused, it uses `focusColor`. For the long press it uses the `splashColor`. Yo can wrap with Theme and provide splashColor.

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    splashColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  child: DropdownButton<String>(
    dropdownColor: Colors.pink, // main bg 
    focusColor: Colors.amber,// when focused
    value: dropdownValue,
```